# What is meant in php by a "typed result"

Tags: php, xpath

Greets - Sorry for how basic this question will be. However, I'm learning XPath and have run into a phrase I do not understand. It is found in the documentation for DOMXPath::evaluate -

> Returns a typed result if possible or a DOMNodeList containing all nodes matching the given XPath expression.
>
> If the expression is malformed or the contextnode is invalid, DOMXPath::evaluate() returns FALSE.

What is meant by "typed result"? Is this referring to results returned by the various XPath aggregate functions used in a query string - int, string, array, etc? Since PHP is a loosely typed language, this phrase confuses me.

Thank you in advance for any answers.

Comment: type result = a specific type of result: array, string, domnodelist, etc... PHP may be loosely typed, but all that means is you're generally free to convert between types, and PHP will do so automatically depending on context, but EVERY bit of data still has a fundamental type associated with it.

Comment: OK. I see. I tried a comparison between DOMXPath::evaluate and query using the aggregate 'count(//form/div/div/*)' as the expression. For the document I am testing with, evaluate returned 'double(6)' as I expected. A typed result. query returned 'class DOMNodeList#3 (0) { }', a DOMNodeList as documented. Thanks Marc